# Why am I getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code, the class counters is calling class counter.
I am trying to follow the youtube tutorials:
[Tutotial 1:24:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0&t=4050s).

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Counter from './counter';

class Counters extends Component {
    state = {  
        counters: [
            { id: 1, value: 4},
            { id: 2, value: 0},
            { id: 3, value: 0},
            { id: 4, value: 0}
        ]
    };


    render() { 
        return (  
            <div>
                { this.state.counters.map(counter => 
                <Counter key={counter.id} value={counter.value} selected={true}/>)} 
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Counters;
```

and

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Counter extends Component {

    state = {  
        count: this.props.value,
        tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
    } 

    handleIncrement = product => {
        console.log(product);
        this.setState({ count : this.state.count + 1})
    }

    handleDecrement = () => {
        this.setState({ count : this.state.count - 1})
    }

    render() { 

        console.log('props', this.props);

        return (
            <div>
                <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
                <button onClick={() => this.handleIncrement({id:1})} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2">Increment</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleDecrement} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2">Decrement</button>
            </div>
          );
    }

    getBadgeClasses() {
        let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
        classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
        return classes;
    }

    formatCount() {
        const { count } = this.state;
        return count === 0 ? <h1>Zero</h1> : count;
    }
}


export default Counter;
```

However I get following error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do one of the following two things to fix this:

- Remove the constructor for `Counter`
- Add the `props` argument to your constructor and pass it to super

For the second option, your constructor would look like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
```

But removing the constructor has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because where you try to initialize your state, it actually hasn't mapped the props.

This can easily be avoided by initializing your state in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {  
        count: props.value,
        tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
    };
}
```